# partially cooked meats

Tags: meatballs

I am making tomato sauce.  I plan to brown several kinds of meats and poultry today and finish cooking them in my tomato sauce tomorrow.  Is there some health issue I should be concerned with partially cooked meats that will spend over night in the refrig before putting them in my tomato sauce that will be cooking for several hours?

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a safety issue here as long as you brown the meat soon after taking it out of the fridge and immediately re-refrigerate it. Just don't leave it out of the refrigerator longer than necessary to do the browning. It wouldn't hurt to save the browned meat in a clean container, not the one that that held the raw meat.